# Duplicity keeps telling last full backup date: none

Tags: backup, duplicity, duply

I am using duply wrapper script and made a full backup of my folder to another location, when I then try to run incr backup, Duplicity keeps telling me, that last full backup date is none.

```
Warning, found signatures but no corresponding backup files
Warning, found incomplete backup sets, probably left from aborted session
Last full backup date: none
Last full backup is too old, forcing full backup
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive dir: /root/.cache/duplicity/duply_my_profile

Found 0 secondary backup chains.
No backup chains with active signatures found
Also found 0 backup sets not part of any chain,
and 1 incomplete backup set.
```

Command line duplicity was called with (note: I called dry-run here just to produce this output and send it to a file, since the full backup takes almost a day. Was ran without dry-run before. "nas-cloud" is defined in .ssh/config along with the ssh keys. The connection works, the files are appearing on the other side and updated):

```
duplicity 0.7.11 (December 31, 2016)
Args: /usr/bin/duplicity incr --name duply_my_profile --encrypt-key \
******** --sign-key ******** --verbosity 9 \
--full-if-older-than 1M --par2-redundancy 15 --asynchronous-upload \
--force --dry-run --exclude-filelist /root/.duply/my_profile/exclude \ 
/opt/storage/ par2+pexpect+sftp://nas-cloud//backups/

Linux debian 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 
/usr/bin/python 2.7.13 (default, Nov 24 2017, 17:33:09) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
```

Something seems to be wrong with the signatures
How can I fix this or what can I do to find more about this issue?

```
0 files exist on backend
4 files exist in cache
Extracting backup chains from list of files: []
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
StartTime 1523349943.62 (Tue Apr 10 10:45:43 2018)
EndTime 1523350235.82 (Tue Apr 10 10:50:35 2018)
ElapsedTime 292.20 (4 minutes 52.20 seconds)
SourceFiles 1284474
SourceFileSize 330150901549 (307 GB)
NewFiles 643763
NewFileSize 330150901549 (307 GB)
DeletedFiles 0
ChangedFiles 0
ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 643763
RawDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 0 (0 bytes)
Errors 0
-------------------------------------------------

Releasing lockfile /root/.cache/duplicity/duply_my_profile/lockfile.lock
Removing still remembered temporary file /tmp/duplicity-mtXuus-tempdir/mkstemp-5_L1Mx-1
--- Finished state OK at 10:50:36.835 - Runtime 00:04:57.692 ---
```

Comment: Does really no one have a solution to this problem?